# Trying to appened an HTML select menu

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to appended an HTML select menu via jquery, but nothing shows up.  This code ran fine when I only appended the textbox.  When I added the `<select>` menu, it stopped working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").click(function(){
$("#pTags").append("
<select>
    <option>Volvo</option>
</select>
<input type='text' placeholder='Class #'><br>


");
});
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r72tc/)

Comment: Can you post on jsfiddle? including the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
var htmlString = "<div>This is a string.</div>";
```

This fails:

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>
  This is a string.
</div>";
```

Sometimes this is desirable for readability.

Add backslashes to get it to work:

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>\
  This is a string.\
</div>";
```

Or plus sign

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>"+
  "This is a string."+
"</div>";
```

or furthermore you can see other ways and try the one that you liked most [**HERE**](http://jsperf.com/zp-string-concatenation/5)

For you, checkout this snippet or [**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/r72tc/11/) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var opts = [
    'Volvo',
    'Ford',
    'BMW'
  ];

  $("#add").on('click', function(){          
    htmlString = "<select>";
    for (var i in opts) htmlString += "<option>"+opts[i]+"</option>";
    htmlString += "</select><input type='text' placeholder='Class #'><br>";

    $("#pTags").append(htmlString);

  });
});​
```

Comment: i tried the backslashes and it didn't work.  check out my updated jsfiddle

Comment: i appreciate that, but is there someway I can write this without the slashes.  Eventually, this select menu will have about 50 options

Comment: As you can see in the **HERE** link, it has more than five ways to do the same task and the performace test for each example. If you update your question with the format I can try to find the best solution. In advance regular concat with one line and array join concatenation are the fastest ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split a string over several lines like that, do it all on one line or add to the string and you'll be fine:

```
$("#pTags").append("<select><option>Volvo</option></select><input type='text' placeholder='Class #'><br>");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r72tc/4/)

or :

```
var html =  '<select>';
    html += '<option>Volvo</option>';
    html += '</select>';
    html += '<input type="text" placeholder="Class #">';
    html += '<br>';
    html.appendTo("#pTags");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r72tc/9/)

Comment: This is what Mozilla recommend, but I like the backslashes :P

Comment: is there a better way to do all of this? like where i can just write my html with the whitespace?